# Polar Coordinates Volume of Solid, Angle for integration?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, volume

I'm trying to understand how to find the angle for the integration in polar coordinate form for a solid.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to solve:
Find the volume of the solid bounded by the graphs of the given equations:

r= cos(theta), z= 2+ x^2 + y^2, z = 0.

I realize that the radius can go from 0 to cos(theta), and the function to the integrate is (2+r^2) r dr d(theta)

However, I can't seem to understand how to find the angle of integration.
in the solutions, it uses symmetry and becomes **2∫from 0 to pi/2** ∫ from 0 to cos(theta) of [(2+r^2) r dr d(theta)].

The only thing I can't understand is how the angle was found, and why the integral was then multiplied by two.

Thank you very much.